# CreateChooser is not working in Android v5.1

Tags: xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android, file-sharing

I am using intent to share pdf files. I am restricting apps when share file. I want to share the file to Good document, Kindle and drop box alone. I am using the below code to achieve this.But the below code is not working in android v5.1. The device have the required app to share. But it is showing **"No apps can perform this action"** when share. Can you anyone suggest your ideas to resolve this?

```
var pathFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
            var m_documentMobiNames = shortName + "." + fileType;
            var mobileFileName = Path.Combine(pathFile, m_documentMobiNames);
            var shareIntentsLists = new List<Intent>();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            sendIntent.SetType("application/pdf");
            var resInfos = context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);
            if (resInfos.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var resInfo in resInfos)
                {
                    string packageName = resInfo.ActivityInfo.PackageName;
                    if (packageName.Contains("com.google.android.apps.docs") || packageName.Contains("com.dropbox.android") || packageName.Contains("com.amazon.kindle"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.ActivityInfo.Name));
                        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
                        intent.SetType("application/pdf");
                        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file://" + mobileFileName));
                        intent.SetPackage(packageName);
                        shareIntentsLists.Add(intent);
                    }
                }
            }


            if (shareIntentsLists.Count > 0)
            {

                chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(new Intent(), "Share with");
                chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mobileFileName));
                chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, shareIntentsLists.ToArray());
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                chooserIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartActivity(chooserIntent);
                await Task.FromResult(true);

            }
```

Comment: Are you saying it works on all other APIs, but not API-22?

Comment: Yes. its working in other API version. but not in API-22